# algorithm merge sort because after dividing the list and sorting the first two values ​in my case 16 and 44 why is the function executed again?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I was studying the logic behind the merge sort algorithm in python. After dividing the list and ordering the first two values ​​in my case 16 and 44, why the function is executed again?

This is the code:

```
def MergeSort(list):
    if len(list)>1:
        mid = len(list)//2 #splits list in half
        left = list[:mid]
        right = list[mid:]

        MergeSort(left) #repeats until length of each list is 1
        MergeSort(right)

        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
        while a < len(left) and b < len(right):
            if left[a] < right[b]:
                list[c]=left[a]
                a = a + 1
            else:
                list[c]=right[b]
                b = b + 1
            c = c + 1
        while a < len(left):
            list[c]=left[a]
            a = a + 1
            c = c + 1

        while b < len(right):
            list[c]=right[b]
            b = b + 1
            c = c + 1
    return list
```

According to my logic once I get to the end of the function since there is no cycle I should exit the function and yet (as it should be) the other two values ​​are also analyzed and sorted.

Comment: I don't see 16 nor 44 anywhere. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: This sounds like a case of recursion confusion, but I'm not certain. Can you give us a little more information? Are you single-stepping in the debugger? A complete example with a detailed description of your observations would help a lot.

Comment: sorry the values ​​16 and 44 referred to the list that I feed to the function , the list is:
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    a=[44,16,83,7]
  print(MergeSort(a))

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be working fine. There is no need for `return list` since MergeSort is modifying the original list.

> and yet (as it should be) the other two values ​​are also analyzed and sorted

The code seems to be working fine. There is no need for `return list` since MergeSort is modifying the original list.

> and yet (as it should be) the other two values ??are also analyzed and sorted

The function MergeSort call itself twice:

```
        MergeSort(left)
        MergeSort(right)
```

The order will be depth first, left first. No merging takes place until there are only 2 elements to merge: 1 in left [44], 1 in right [16], which it merges to produce [16,44]. After that it returns to call MergeSort(right) for [83,7], which merges to produce [7,83]. It then returns back to the prior level of nesting to merge [16,44] with [7,83]. Showing the order of operations:

```
44 16 83  7
44 16
44
   16
16 44
      83  7
      83
          7
       7 83
 7 16 44 83
```